# Reading .json file and converting unicode data to utf-8

Tags: python

I never really understood how encoding and decoding works in python and I am used to come across this type of problems frequently. I have to read a json file and compare some of its values with other data.

In one of the files I have the string `BAIXA DA INSCRI\u00c7\u00c3O ESTADUAL` which should become `BAIXA DA INSCRICAO ESTADUAL`. I am reading the file like this:

```
with codecs.open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    filedata = json.loads(file.read())
```

However the string is read as unicode and represented like `u'BAIXA DA INSCRI\xc7\xc3O ESTADUAL'`

How can I make this happen, and how is the proper way to work with codecs in python?

Comment: From where do you read it? what is codecs?

Comment: `codecs` using to set file encoding and not needed in Python 3 where `open` has `encoding` param. When your read `inscrição` from file it's not magically interprets letters ç => c and ã => a, you've to set proper interpretation rules. It's not encoding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you want to remove any diacritics from your text. You can try to use the normal form D (for decomposed) of unicode and filter out high codes:

```
txt = u'BAIXA DA INSCRI\xc7\xc3O ESTADUAL'
txt = u''.join(i for i in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', t) if ord(i) < 128).encode('ASCII')
```

It should give the (byte) string:

```
'BAIXA DA INSCRICAO ESTADUAL'
```